How to disable the middle-click action inside of KDE's Present Windows feature?
In KDE's Present Windows effect, which shows all windows zoomed out as thumbnails, middle clicking on one of the thumbnails closes the window.
I find this behavior dangerous, because I end up closing random windows.
Is there a way to disable it?
(I don't want to disable Present Windows entirely, nor disable middle-clicking in general)
I'm using Kubuntu 24.04 with KDE Plasma 5.27.11
